# Fully filled capacitors with parallel dielectrics problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, dielectric

consider that we have two dielectrics inside a capacitor as shown in the picture, let0s consider also that Q is the charge of the capacitor and d the distance between the two plates , the first dielectric occupy a surface of S/3 with a dielectric constant of er1 and the second a surface of 2S/3 with a dielectric constant of er2, the question is calculate the electric field inside the capacitor and the surface density of the induced charge[image]

During the calculation I faced the following doubts:
I applied gauss theorem to the flux density in both areas of the dielectrics and I got:

[image]

***$σ$ is the surface density of the free charges $=Q/S$,***

[image]

doing the same with the second surface I got that

[image]

and because my two dielectric are in parallel so $E1=E2$

this gives me

[image]

BUT this not true!
so where did my logic fails?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is the density of the free charges σ on the capacitor plates isn't uniform. it varies from region 1 to region 2.